# WSO2 IMB MQ connection with new created Queues

Tags: wso2, ibm-mq

I have a question,I new in ESB so I used the manual to create connection with my ESB and IBM MQ

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Configure+with+IBM+WebSphere+MQ

on the end I create .bindings file and used. Everything worked fine. So Im able to read messages from Queues that exist in QueueManager.

QUESTION:

- Am I need to rebuild .binding file every time when I create new Queue?
  is there a way to use/see newly created Queues without rebuild a .binding  file?
- For connection in \repository\conf\axis2.xml  I used

> ```
> > <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" > locked="false">queue</parameter>
> > <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false">**myname**</parameter>
> > <parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false">**mypassword**</parameter>
> ```

I see this on http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.com/search/label/WSo2%20ESB

but maybe I should use this

```
> <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType"
> locked="false">**topic**</parameter>
>             <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">ivtT</parameter>
```

Comment: I found that I need to use WMQInitialContextFactory and change Axis2 configuration of ESB like  <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">{MQ_SERVER_IP}:{PORT}/{CHANNEL_NAME}</parameter>
                            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">{QUEUE_MANAGER_NAME}</parameter>
                            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
                            <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">{QUEUE_NAME}</parameter> but  why need to define queue name ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I tried every single combination. Working solution in my case is :

**WMQInitialContextFactory** is not recommended... starting from version 8 IBM MQ they using  ONLY **RefFSContextFactory**

so after creating .binding file the repository\conf\axis2.xml should look like

```
      <parameter name="esbMngr" locked="false">
            <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:/home/wso2admin/wso2esb-5.0.0/jndi</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">GSTQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false">userName</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false">userPassword</parameter>
      </parameter>
```

.....

where **GSTQueueConnectionFactory** is ConectionFactory name that is defined in .binding file

So proxy server looks like :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
           name="TMSLeaseMQParser"
           startOnLoad="true"
           statistics="disable"
           trace="disable"
           transports="jms">    
<target>
          <inSequence>        
             <log level="full">           
             </log>
          </inSequence>
          <outSequence>
             <send/>
          </outSequence>
          <faultSequence/>         
</target>    
<parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</parameter>    
<parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">TMSALease</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
          <rules xmlns="">
             <jmsProperty>contectType</jmsProperty>
             <default>application/xml</default>
          </rules>    
</parameter>    
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">esbMngr</parameter>    <description/> 
</proxy>
```

So **esbMngr** is name of section defined in axis2.xml while **TMSALease** is your message queue that you are reading from IBM MQ

I hope is this is going to save some time someone ... Any feedback is welcome

NOTE: communication can be tricky. Be sure that you check that your userName have access to queue, read more in IBM Technote "[2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED Connecting to WebSphere MQ from WebSphere Application Server via CLIENT Bindings](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21636093)"

To check MQ OAM permissions us the `dspmqaut` command, for example:

```
dspmqaut -m WS02ESBManager -n TMSALease -t queue -p userName
```

To set MQ OAM permissions us the `setmqaut` command, for example:

```
setmqaut -m WS02ESBManager -n TMSALease -t queue -p userName+put
```

Also sometimes help if you :

Disable **Channel authentication records** in **Communication** in **Properties**  of queue manager ...